# Angular.js angular-dragdrop custom callback function not found

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, angularjs, jquery-draggable

I'm using this [plugin](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop) with Angular. In the documentation it says that

> onDrop        callback method to be invoked a draggable is dropped into the droppable

so I tried using it like this (the relevant part is the **onDrop="myCallback"**):

```
<div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" 
        onDrop="myCallback" ng-model='list1' 
        data-jqyoui-options="optionsList1" 
        jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="btn btn-info btn-draggable" 
              ng-repeat="item in list1" 
              ng-show="item.title" 
              data-drag="{{item.drag}}" 
              data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" 
              ng-model="list1" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true}">                
        {{item.title}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And defined the function on the scope like so:

```
$scope.myCallback = function(event, ui){
    console.log('Dropped into something');
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kiYrIU?p=preview

As you can see from the Plunker, this doesn't work, for some reason the callback function isn't found (it's not looking on the scope perhaps?).

I have tried multiple variations of this, like `onDrop="myCallback(event, ui)"` or `onDrop="myCallback"` etc. None of these worked.

Is this a bug or am I simply not using it correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the examples I've seen you're doing it wrong.

1. `onDrop` callback should be declared in `jqyoui-droppable`

   jqyoui-droppable = "{..., onDrop: 'myCallback', ...}"

But look @ this for a more complete code [here](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/blob/master/demo/dnd-frameworks.html)

**Solution**

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FSLaeg?p=preview)

Lil bug though, it drops the first 2 items and nothing more but this should help you on your way. Update: I just noticed you had a limit placed on it, silly me. In that case, it's solved